# get data from array of functions

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, function, themoviedb-api

i got the data from this array but when i add it to the loop to show all the arrays it only show me only one array
help pleaseeee

this is the problem :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/gmg4I.png

the function to get data from api ( the problem isnt here this works fine )

```
function Movie(id){
fetch(`https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/${id}?api_key=${apikey}`)
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((data) => {
    name = data.original_title;
    img = data.poster_path;
    link = name.replace(/[^a-zA-Z\s/ ]/g, "")
    var MyArray = {'name':`${name}`, 'img':`${img}`, 'link':`/movies/${link}.html`}
    console.log(MyArray)
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.error(err);
    });
}
```

The Array :

```
var MyMovies = [
    Movie(238),
    Movie(899082),
    Movie(899),
]
```

the function to display all arrays (the problem is here i think)

```
function LoadMovies(){
    buildTable(MyMovies)
    function buildTable(data){
        var table = document.querySelector('#movies')
    
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
            var row = `<img id="img" src="${"https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w342/" + img}" alt="${name}" class="thumb" onclick="location.href='${link}';">`
            table.innerHTML += row
        }
    }
}
```

the `console.log` show this :
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'img')`

Comment: You're displaying your API key to everyone, chief

Comment: You seem to be expecting some data to be returned from the `Movie` function, but you never return anything.

Comment: @Moncef, nope, still clearly visible in the edit history. I suggest you copy it, delete this and paste everything as a new question.

Comment: Your Movie function is Async. You need to await to get the results.

Comment: @ShamilMammadov can you show me an example ?

Comment: @mstephen19 can you show me an example ?

Comment: MyArray is not an array. You really should use PromiseAll() and have your Movie function return the fetch.

Comment: @Moncef i have put it as an answer

Answer (score 1):

The main problem is that you `Movie` function doesn't return anything. You need to return the results of the `fetch` method. And later you need to use `Promise.all(MyMovies)` to get all results from the all `Movie()` calls.

This is how you need to do it:

```
async function Movie(id) {
  return fetch(`https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/${id}?api_key=${apikey}`)
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((data) => {
      name = data.original_title;
      img = data.poster_path;
      link = name.replace(/[^a-zA-Z\s/ ]/g, "");
      return {
        name,
        img,
        link: `/movies/${link}.html`
      };
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.error(err);
    });
}

const MyMovies = [Movie(238), Movie(899082), Movie(899)]

async function LoadMovies() {
  const table = document.querySelector("#movies");
  const movies = await Promise.all(MyMovies);

  movies.forEach((m) => {
    var row = `<YOUR_RAW>`;

    table.innerHTML += row;
  });
}
```

Comment: You have a bug, nothing is being returned in the fetch. And when you fix it, please change the incorrect variable name.

Comment: Yes, just copied the his code, didn't look that he didn't return anything from `.then` in fetch

Comment: im getting this error code in the console :

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: await is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules

Comment: @ShamilMammadov it didnt work, can i give you a live link for visual code so you can access the source code from your browser to fix it ?

Comment: @Moncef yes, you can give it to me.

Comment: @ShamilMammadov what is your discord, telegram?

Comment: @moncef you can give me yours, i will write you

Answer (score 0):

The img is undefined in the case the API doesn't return anything or when the API is processing. Use async/await to wait until the API return something, once you get the data, img will be assigned a value and there would be no error.
Use this piece of code:

```
async function Movie(id) {
  return fetch(`https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/${id}?api_key=${apikey}`)
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((data) => {
      name = data.original_title;
      img = data.poster_path;
      link = name.replace(/[^a-zA-Z\s/ ]/g, "");
      return {
        name,
        img,
        link: `/movies/${link}.html`
      };
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.error(err);
    });
}

const MyMovies = [Movie(238), Movie(899082), Movie(899)]

async function LoadMovies() {
  const table = document.querySelector("#movies");
  const movies = await Promise.all(MyMovies);

  movies.forEach((m) => {
    var row = `<YOUR_RAW>`;

    table.innerHTML += row;
  });
}
```

OR

you can wrap your for loop in if condition,

```
function LoadMovies(){
    buildTable(MyMovies)
    function buildTable(data){
        var table = document.querySelector('#movies')
    if(img){
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
            var row = `<img id="img" src="${"https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w342/" + img}" alt="${name}" class="thumb" onclick="location.href='${link}';">`
            table.innerHTML += row
        }
}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I find multiple errors.
First of all, you need the values of all Promise results.
I would do it like this:

```
var MyMovies = [
    238,
    899082,
    899,
];

// Promise.all stops, if one request fails, this method doesn't.
var index = 0;
var answers = [];
(function loop() {
    var value = MyMovies[index];
    fetch(`https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/${value}?api_key=${apikey}`)
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then(data => {
        var link = data.original_title.replace(/[^a-zA-Z\s/ ]/g, "");
        answers.push({
            name: data.original_title,
            img: data.poster_path,
            link: `/movies/${link}.html`,
        });
    });
    index++;
    if (index < MyMovies.length) {
        loop();
    }
})();
buildTable(answers);
```

after that, you should be able to iterate over the array, like you do. Just make sure, you also access to the object

```
function buildTable(data){
    var table = document.querySelector('#movies');
    for (var i = 0, o; o = data[i]; i++){
        var row = `<img id="img" src="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w342/${o.img}" alt="${o.name}" class="thumb" onclick="location.href='${o.link}';">`
        table.innerHTML += row
    }
}
```